# Microsoft Teams notifications break when posting as bot with "onBehalfOf"

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We are facing a weird issue with our Teams bot. Our customers reported, that if you @-mention someone in a reply to our bot message, they will not receive any notification (no feed nor banner notification) for this mention. We can reproduce this.

[image]

After a lot of testing, we found the culprit: We post the bot message with "onBehalfOf" (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/respond-to-task-module-submit?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-1#user-attribution-for-bots-messages) to make it more clear that it was based on a user action. If we do this, ALL notifications for this thread break, and users are not notified about @ mentions anymore.

Not sure we are using it right or it's indeed a bug in Teams?

Comment: we are looking into it.

Comment: I've filed a Bug for Messaging Extension team. I will update you once this got resolved